# IBM bluemix Git repository push and pull requests

Tags: git, http, service, ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

I have created an Tomcat server application in Bluemix and enabled the Continuous Delivery service for it. It automatically created a Git Repository. However, with that Git URL if i try to import that project into local Eclipse, it is not authorizing me to pull the code from the URL.
I used an IBM password to access the Git repository.

What is the problem in authenticating me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to your Git profile and open the settings page. Than create a personal Access token. Use this Token with the username instead of your bluemix password.

[image: Access]

Comment: Thanks it worked...is it possible to modify the token and grantin access to others?